# C program works on VS Code but doesn't work on Dev-C++

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, dev-c++

So I need to sum the votes received per candidate but the sum becomes negative. I tried using the debugger in Dev-C++ but the program stops after I enter the votes so I used VS Code instead to debug the program. But when I run it, the output was correct even though I didn't change any code when I opened it in VS Code. I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11 and VS Code 1.65.0. I can't switch to VS Code because my teacher requires us to use either Dev-C++ or Turbo C++. I can't use Turbo C++ as well since it freezes every time I run any program using it.

THE CODE:

```
/****************************************************************************

MACHINE PROBLEM 1

The results from the mayor's race have been reported by each precinct as
follows:

            Candidate   Candidate   Candidate   Candidate
Precincts   A           B           C           D
1           192         48          206         37
2           147         90          312         21
3           186         12          121         38
4           114         21          408         39
5           267         13          382         29

Write a program to do the following:

a. Print out the table with the appropriate headings for the rows and
    columns.
b. Compute and print the total number of votes received by each
    candidate and the percent of the total votes cast.
c. If any one candidate received over 50 percent of the total votes, the
   program should print a message declaring that candidate the winner.
d. If no candidate received 50 percent of the votes, the program should
    print a message declaring a run-off between the two candidates who
    received the highest number of votes; two candidates should be identified
    by their letter names.
e. Run the program once with the preceding data and once with candidate C
    receiving only 108 votes in precinct 4. (note: test values are not
    limited to the preceding data)

Note: Use Array for this machine problem

*****************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void headings();
void cHeadings();

char candidates[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
int precincts[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int votes[5][4];

COORD coord = {0,0};
void gotoxy(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    char border = '|';
    int i, j;
    
    // Print headings

    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\t%c\t", border);
    headings();
    printf("\nPrecincts");
    printf("\t%c\t", border);
    cHeadings();
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    //// Print precinct number
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d", precincts[i]);
        printf("\t\t%c\t", border);
        if (i != 4)
            printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    // Table data
    
    int xcoord = 24, ycoord = 4;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++, ycoord++) {
        xcoord = 24;
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++, xcoord += 16) {
            gotoxy(xcoord, ycoord);
            scanf("%d", &votes[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    // Total number of votes per candidate

    float sum[1][4];

    printf("\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\t\t%c\t", border);
    headings();
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t%c\t", border);
    cHeadings();
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Total no. of votes\t");
    printf("%c\t", border);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum[0][j] += votes[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\t\t", (int) sum[0][i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    return 0;
}

// Print "Candidate" headings

void headings()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        /*if (i == 0) {
            printf("\t");
        } else {*/
            printf("Candidate\t");
        //}
        if (i == 4) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

// Print candidate letter names

void cHeadings()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%c\t\t", candidates[i]);
        if (i == 4) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

// gotoxy()

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

OUTPUT (DEV-C++):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                |       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate
Precincts       |       A               B               C               D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               |       192             48              206             37
2               |       147             90              312             21
3               |       186             12              121             38
4               |       114             21              408             39
5               |       267             13              382             29
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        |       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate
                        |       A               B               C               D
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total no. of votes      |       -2147483648             -2147483648             1429            164
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------
Process exited after 43.82 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

OUTPUT (VS CODE):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                |       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate
Precincts       |       A               B               C               D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               |       192             48              206             37
2               |       147             90              312             21
3               |       186             12              121             38
4               |       114             21              408             39
5               |       267             13              382             29
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        |       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate       Candidate
                        |       A               B               C               D
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total no. of votes      |       906             184             1429            164
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show us your code (add it to the question).  There probably _is_ something wrong with it, but if we can't see it we have no way of knowing.  As for _my teacher requires us to use either Dev-C++ or Turbo C++_, well, WHY?  Nobody uses those anymore, and your experiences with them tells us why.

Comment: @PaulSanders I did include the code, is it not showing? Sorry, I don't use Stack Overflow much.

Comment: why is your sum a 2D array; you only use sum[0]?

Comment: Oh sorry.  Scroll down, Murgatroyd.

Comment: Try not casting your float to int, instead use %.0f to print the value rounded to no decimal places.

Comment: @djna Oh right lol. I'm new to arrays. I'll try making it 1D and see if it works, thanks.

Comment: @djna Using %.0f worked, thanks!!

Comment: I doubt that the 2d array thing is the source of the problem, it's just "unclean" :-) I'm guessing you're seeing an "interesting" conversion behaviour when casting. Hopefully using the %f will help.

Comment: @Egor's answer is correct but a bit short on detail.  Assuming you change `sum` to be a 1D array, you want `float sum [4] = { 0 };`  That's why you're getting different results on different compilers - your code currently exhibits Undefined Behaviour, and here endeth the first lesson on the kind of trouble that can cause. That might not be the only place in your code where you have forgotten to initialise something, but a quick scan through did not reveal any others.  And tell your prof to stop cramping your style!

Comment: @PaulSanders Why can't I just put `float sum [4];`? What's the difference between `float sum [4];` and `float sum [4] = { 0 };`?

Comment: `float sum [4];` does not initialise `sum`.  In consequence, it might contain anything at all.  I added something to my previous comment about this.  OTOH, `float sum [4] = { 0 };` initialises all 4 elements of `sum` to zero, which of course is what you want here.  Moral: always initialise local variables.  The cost is minimal and it prevents bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you forgot to clean local variables before to use. Just use `float sum [4] = { 0 };`

It is necessary due to memory which is allocated locally would be filled by any values. C standard aware just for cleaning of global variables.

Comment: @Yunnosch, Sorry, I didn't get your question

Comment: When you are declaring a variable -- you just "reserve" address in memory. But if you don't clean it before to use -- you may get random value, for example it may contains value of local variable from previous function which was executed.

Comment: Someone already answered it but this works as well, thanks! I replaced `sum[0][j] += votes[i][j];` with `float sum [4] = { 0 };` and  `printf("%d\t\t", (int) sum[0][i]);` with `printf("%d\t\t", (int) sum[i]);`.

Comment: > How do the "any values" turn into a problem?

Due to each IDE would set there extra flags for compilation, we would see such behavior.